# How to launch a new instance of Google Chrome from the command line?

Tags: ssh, google-chrome

Is there *any* way I can launch a new instance of Google Chrome from the command line? I'm not referring to opening a new window - I want a new *instance*. Here's why:

Suppose I open Chrome and navigate to a page somewhere. Then I SSH into the same account from somewhere else. When I run:

```
google-chrome
```

...all I get is a new tab in the existing window. This is absolutely useless when I'm connected via SSH.

How can I launch a *separate* instance of Chrome that runs in the same account, but is usable with SSH?

Comment: Incognito mode? `google-chrome --incognito` ?

Comment: @Kaustubh doesnt help

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27344). A workaround is to pass the argument `--user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d)` (or you can use any temporary or empty directory) to start a new session.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for details on how to do that. I also posted it back at http://superuser.com/a/457045/132608, which was the first StackExchange variant of this question I found.

Comment: This no longer works with recent versions of Chrome, but you can effectively start with a "blank slate" new account by specifying a temporary or empty directory, e.g. `chromium-browser --user-data-dir=/tmp`

Comment: And still a bug, 9 years later :)

Comment: And still 11 years later....

Comment: What if you want to use keep the user's profile (i.e. browsing history, saved sessions, etc)?

Comment: @MahmoudMousaHamad, I don't think Chrome can concurrently support _two entirely independent instances_ which are manipulating the _same_ user's session data. In my opinion, that would be a lot of work to implement, and the use case seems pretty unclear… there's little point in keeping separate instances if they're going to access all the same data. As I take it, this question is about starting another wholly separate/isolated instance of Chrome.

Comment: For me, the original answer works but not the comment from @Dan about using `/tmp` (likely since this means that each new instance of chrome will share the profile created in `/tmp` by the first instance). The original answer ensures there is always a new empty directory created for each instance of chromium.

Answer (score 13):

I do this

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome
mkdir /tmp/chrome2
find . -print | cpio -mpdv /tmp/chrome2 # there was no cp -R in my day!
rm -fr /tmp/chrome2/Singleton*
rm -fr /tmp/chrome2/Session* 
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome2/
```

Instead of the cpio/rm lines I'm using this now

```
rsync -av --delete --exclude=/Singleton* --exclude=/Session* ~/.config/google-chrome/ /tmp/chrome2/
```

Comment: This still works as of 2019.  There is no Session* files and I just made a copy of the directory to ~/.config/google-chrome-2 manually and deleted the Singleton files..  Then an executable bash file in your path named `google-chrome-2` containing `google-chrome --user-data-dir=/home/<username>/.config/google-chrome-2` and now you have a way to set up a launcher to alt instance.  I needed this to be able to cast to two different devices at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Use `--new-window` parameter.

Like:

```
google-chrome --new-window www.google.com
```

Comment: `google.chrome ...` not `chrome ...`

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha thanks, I changed it to `google-chrome`

Comment: Read the question: *I'm not referring to opening a new window - I want a new instance.*

Comment: this does not work