# Google Chrome browser, how to permanently disable this disturbing toolbar?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, google-chrome, chromium, browser

In my Ubuntu Google Chrome browser, often showing a disturbing toolbar, i am running it in command line kiosk mode.

How can i via command line mention never to show such toolbars? (after pressing X it disappear but again when page refresh it shows up, how can i disable those toolbars completely via command line launch?)

[image]

Comment: Are you talking specifically about the translation toolbar? Why don't you just disable it all together from the Chrome settings and it won't disturb you ever again, even if you run Chrome from the command line? Chrome > Settings > under Language, uncheck "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language I read".

Comment: NO - command line such as `-disable-translate` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a `--disable-translate` switch that can be passed from the command line.

**`google-chrome --kiosk www.france.fr`**

[image]

**`google-chrome --disable-translate --kiosk www.france.fr`**

[image]

> **Note:** some extra information I found is that if there's already another instance of Chrome running, running it from the command-line will show `Created new window in existing browser session`, which has proved to ignore the switches passed in the command, so you won't be able to pass the `--disable-translate` switch, so you'll need to close all instances first. However, if you want to run a new instance from the command line alongside the existing instance, you can do `google-chrome --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d) --kiosk --disable-translate` (or another directory). This involves the creation of a new user data directory.
>
> Source: the answers [**here**](https://askubuntu.com/q/35392/52726) and [**here**](https://superuser.com/q/423272).

There are lots of other switches available in Chrome/Chromium that can be used. You can find them listed [**here**](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) and [**here**](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

Comment: I have another strange problem

Comment: This problem is a nightmare: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78454/how-to-tell-chromium-browser-to-run-a-url-as-single-instance-not-multiple-instan

Comment: I don't know much about that, but I'll post a comment on your question there.

Answer (score 0):

Why not disabling it? Try this.

- In Chrome, click the Customize menu and control Google Chrome then click Options.
- Click the Advanced category.
- In the box Translate, uncheck the box Propose me to translate the pages that are written in a language I can not read.

Comment: NO - i have only SSH access, command line something like `-disable-translate` ?